# c# Unit Testing errors

Tags: c#, unit-testing

im trying to get familiar with unit testing , but I keep getting this annoying error and I have no idea why. I made a class that just divides 2 numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DivideNum
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int doStuff(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int result = num1 / num2;
            return result;


        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I then made my unit test

```
using DivideNum;
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            //arrange
            int a = 10;
            int b = 2;
            int result = 5;

            //act

        }
    }
}
```

i added a reference to my DivideNum namespace and added using DivideNum , but i still cant get a reference to the DivideNum class in my testing class. It wont show up at all in my testing code. why cant i use my DivideNum class in my Test class?

Comment: Because the class `Program` is not marked public. Change it to `public class Program`

Comment: @PeterBons Not private but `intenal` is the default access for classes unless the class is nested.

Comment: @PeterBons my god that was it lol , thank you very much, I didnt even notice that the class was not public.

Comment: @HimBromBeere you're absolutely right, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You´re not calling your system under test in any way (e.g. by calling the `DoStuff`-method), so even making it public won´t change this. However both don´t explain why your test doesn´t appear in the list. Areu you sure you showed the correct code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I added the public to the  class program , and it worked fine. was that not the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Program` class does not have an access type so by default it is `internal`. Changing it to `public` should fix the job.

```
public class Program
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark your class as public if you want to access it from another assembly (Your unit test project). Like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int doStuff(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int result = num1 / num2;
        return result;


    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```